# Angular Js Default filtering is not happening in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to filter my array values on loading of the page by setting default value to the select box,But it is not working[on change of select box it will filter]

### Json

```
[{
        location_id: "2",
        location_name: "location2",
        price: "40",
        product_id: "7",
        product_name: "Burger",
        quantity: "2"
    }, {
        location_id: "3",
        location_name: "location3",
        price: "40",
        product_id: "6",
        product_name: "Dosa",
        quantity: "6"
    }, {
        location_id: "4",
        location_name: "location4",
        price: "40",
        product_id: "5",
        product_name: "cola",
        quantity: "16"
    }
]
```

### html for Select Box

```
<select name="location" class="locationFilter col-md-3 col-md-push-9 col-xs-
12" ng-model="location.location_id">
   <option value="">--Select location--</option>
   <option ng-repeat="item in locationsArray" value="{{item.location_id}}" 
 ng-selected= "item.location_id == defaultLocation">{{item.location_name}}  
 </option>
</select>
```

### html for listing array

```
<div class="col-md-3 itemList" ng-repeat="item in productArray | 
filter:location">{{item.product_name}}</div>
```

In controller I am  defining default value for the location selection as below

`$scope.defaultLocation=3;`

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: use `ng-init` for the location_name

Comment: You should really put your code in a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/)!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. you should learn this https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting before post anything in SO

Comment: Thanks Ramesh.. Now it 's good i think

Comment: let me know your productArray.

Comment: Hi  jesusverma, I already posted json array in the Top of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ng-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue), not value in your option:

> It is mainly used on input[radio] and option elements, so that when
>   the element is selected, the ngModel of that element (or its select
>   parent element) is set to the bound value

Using value will not update the selected item by the value of the ngModel, but ng-value will update it.

```
<select name="location" class="locationFilter col-md-3 col-md-push-9 col-xs-
12" ng-model="location.location_id">
    <option value="">--Select location--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in locationsArray" ng-value="item.location_id">{{item.location_name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

And, since you use `location.location_id` as ng-model, you dont need to set another variable for initialisation( `$scope.defaultLocation` ) just init it by:

```
$scope.location = {location_id: 3};
```

and you dont need the `ng-selected` since ng-model & ng-value do the work for the selected item.

this is a working plunker to show you how: http://plnkr.co/edit/6AXSA8j06gX5yju9a71y?p=preview

Comment: Hi Fetra R. Thank you very much for your answer it worked well for me